# Using Webclient with Foreach Loop to Download Webpages About 100,000

Tags: c#, html, winforms, download, webclient

I am trying to build a small application where when I enter the a list of around 100,000 to 200,0000 urls it should go and download the html and save it in a relative folder.

I have 2 solution but each a some problems I have trying to figure out the best approach.

First Solution: Synchronize Method

Below is the code I am using

```
currentline = 0;
                var lines = txtUrls.Lines.Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).Count();
                string urltext = txtUrls.Text;
                List<string> list = new List<string>(
                           txtUrls.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                lblStatus.Text = "Working";
                btnStart.Enabled = false;

                foreach (string url in list)
                {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(url, @".\pages\page" + currentline + ".html");
                        currentline++;
                    }
                }

                lblStatus.Text = "Finished";
                btnStart.Enabled = true;
```

the code works fine however it's slow and also randomly after 5000 urls it's stops working and the process says it's completed. (Please note I am using this code on background worker but make this code simpler to view I am showing only the relevant code.)

Second Solution : Asynchronize Method

```
int currentline = 0;

                string urltext = txtUrls.Text;
                List<string> list = new List<string>(
                           txtUrls.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                foreach (var url in list)
                {
                    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @".\pages\page" + currentline + ".html");
                    }

                    currentline++;
                    label1.Text = "No.of Lines Completed: " + currentline;
                }
```

this code works super fast but most of the time I am getting downloaded files with 0KB and I am sure the network is fast since I am testing in OVH Dedi server.

Can anyone point what I am doing wrong ? or tips on improving it or entirely different solution to this problem.

Comment: For first solution try extract page downloading to separate thread or task. When you work download in main working thread then ui is not refreshed and app do not respond. Second method you try use asyncronous approach. There are 2 ways how to do it. Use begin and end method or method ending with async. Begin and end methods are older async representatios while methods ending with word 'async' are for use with keywords async await. Your solition mix these 2 ways together.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DownloadFile() try use

```
public  async Task GetData()
{
      WebClient client = new WebClient();
      var data = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

you will get data formated in byte[]. Then you just call:
`File.WriteAllBytes()` to save them to disk.